# How to use a variable(string) in img src tag?

Tags: asp.net, string

I have a code like this:

```
string x="www.abc.com/1.jpg";
```

I should use that string `x` in `img src` tag...

I am writing this code in source file of aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tag you need to write

```
<img src=<%=x%> />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the above (html) example to work:

```
<img src=<%=url% /</div
```

when I had the following script entry in the aspx page:

```
<script runat="server"
public string url;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
url = "images/small/image1.png";
}
</script
```

I am not able to have the aspx:image work though:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="210px" Width="252px" ImageUrl="<%=url%" />
```

I have tried variations of the variable within ImageUrl but it keeps coming up blank or gives an error.
It obviously needs needs a different variable construct.
Let me know who has figured this approach out

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be best if you removed the 'not sure' bit at the end of your answer - you can always add it back in if you find a definitely working solution to this element. Answers should stand on their own without requiring contributions from others.